# Entity Framework Core project with .Net Core and .Net Framework projects

Tags: entity-framework

I am creating a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and the project is using .NET Framework 4.6.1. I am also creating another project for user interface using .NET Core. Since both projects will be using same database so I am thinking to create an another common project using Entity Framework Core. But this project will not be working with .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Could anyone suggest me how to implement this requirement ?